# Unable to read the DATETIME data with the format 'dd/mmm/yyyy:HH:MM:SS'

Tags: regex, matlab

I have these strings and I have to create an array or a table with only the dates expressed in seconds (as a timestamp).

```
192.168.10.149 - - [24/Sep/2021:10:56:49 -0200] "GET /heartbeat.php HTTP/1.1" 200 11828 "-" "Mozilla 8.1"
192.168.6.186 - - [24/Sep/2021:11:34:29 -0200] "GET /heartbeat.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2396 "-" "Mozilla 8.1"
192.168.5.84 - - [24/Sep/2021:12:23:21 -0200] "GET /heartbeat.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2498 "-" "Mozilla 8.1"
192.168.2.197 - - [24/Sep/2021:12:29:35 -0200] "GET /heartbeat.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1801 "-" "Mozilla 8.1"
```

I tried in this way but it doesn't work.

```
table = readtable('Log1.txt', 'Format','%*[^[] [%{dd/mmm/yyyy:HH:MM:SS}D %*[^\n]');
```

I get this error:

```
Error using readtable (line 318)
Unable to read the DATETIME data with the format 'dd/mmm/yyyy:HH:MM:SS'. If the data is not a time, use
```

I didn't convert it to seconds because it's a second step and also because datenum() doesn't accept tables.

Comment: Seems like you are acrrying an extra `m` in the formatting? Note: `dd/mmm/yyyy`

Comment: I checked the wiki and I think it's correct, the months are expressed with 3 characters

Answer (score 1):

On my current version of Matlab (R2019b), month format should be upper cased (`MMM`) and minutes lower cased (`mm`). Be careful of casing, meaning is different.

```
readtable('Log1txt', 'Format','%*[^[] [%{dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss}D %*[^\n]')
```

Also, I would add the time zone offset formatter `Z` to capture it, but `readtable` does not support it, I get this error:

> Error using readtable (line 223)
> The format character vector 'dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z' contains a timezone field. TEXTSCAN does not support reading
> timezones. Use %q to read the data as text and create a datetime array using DATETIME with the 'TimeZone' parameter.

So we can implement this advice as followed:

```
t = readtable('C:\Users\Benoit.Thouy\Documents\new1.txt', 'Format','%*[^[] [ %[^]]', 'ReadVariableNames', false);
table = table(datetime(t.Var1, 'InputFormat', 'dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z', 'TimeZone', 'local');
```